# H.264 or H.265 for personal video backup

Tags: video, h.264, h.265

I have a LG G3 phone and I take personal videos in 1920*1080 resolution. But video size is too big for my backup (5 minutes video is around 700 MB). So I researched a little bit, I encountered H.264 encoding and learned it a little bit and I was able to shrink the video size to 160 MB as almost same quality. Then I encountered H.265 which is said to be next generation encoding (I tried that as well my video went down to 57 MB). Does it make sense to backup my videos in H.265 format now or should I wait until it's mature enough and go for H.264? What if a competing encoding method beats H.265, can I still watch my videos in the future? Any reason that I can't think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does make sense to use H.265. Your main concern should be with playback quality.  H.265 will probably join the long list of formats that are supported by so many freeware and paid programs.  Even if you later from now cannot find a piece of software to read your file, you could use the documentation from ISO or ITU to write software that can, or hire someone else to.  Or, if H.265 falls out of favor, convert your backup files before too much time passes.  H.265 will probably be supported for decades though.